# how to remove space on jspdf autotable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

My pdf is showing table and this table is can small and can long table (depends on the amount of data) , i set if data more than 10 its will new page (addPage) but i have some problem , if addpage its have more space in the midle on pdf you can see at this [image](https://ibb.co/QPqypD6) or this [image]

why this table not continue at top on this second page ? this is my code . can someone help for this ??

this is my code

```
 downloadPDF(){
 // footer
 var  addFooters = doc => {
 const pageCount = doc.internal.getNumberOfPages()

 doc.setFont('helvetica', 'italic')
 doc.setFontSize(8)
 for (var i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) {
   doc.setPage(i)
   doc.text('Page ' + String(i) + ' of ' + String(pageCount), doc.internal.pageSize.width / 2, 587, {
   align: 'center'
    })
  }
 }
   
  var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'pt');

  

   let totals = this.datatotal
   let anggarans = this.dataanggaran 
   let uraian = this.datauraian 
   let tgl = this.datatanggal 
   let digunakan = this.datadigunakan
   let sisa = (this.dataanggaran - (this.datadigunakan + this.datatotal))
  //header
   var header = function (data) {
                doc.setFontSize(18);
                doc.setTextColor(40);
                doc.setFontStyle('normal');

               doc.text(330, 50, 'Pengajuan Pencairan')
              
              
            };
             doc.setFontSize(12)
             doc.text(55, 80,  'Nama Program')
             doc.text(165, 80, ': 1.02.06.1 Program Upaya Kesehatan Masyarakat')
           
             doc.text(55, 100, 'Kegiatan')
             doc.text(165,100, ': 1.02.06.1.5.2.2.26.01.02.01 Pelayanan Kesehatan')
            doc.text(165,120, 'RSUD dr.Soeratno Gemolong Sragen-BLUD ')

             doc.text(55, 140, 'Rincian Kegiatan')
             doc.text(165, 140, ': '+ String(uraian))  
             doc.text(55, 160, 'Bulan Tanggal')
             doc.text(165, 160, ': '+ String(tgl))  

             doc.text(540, 80, 'Anggaran')
             doc.text(660, 80, ':Rp '+ String(this.formatPrice(anggarans)))     
            //  doc.text(130, 100, uraian)           
             doc.text(540, 100, 'Sudah Digunakan')
             doc.text(660, 100, ':Rp '+ String(this.formatPrice(digunakan)))     
             doc.text(540, 140, 'Pengajuan')
             doc.text(660, 140, ':Rp '+ String(this.formatPrice(totals)))   
             doc.text(540, 160, 'Sisa Anggaran')
             doc.text(660, 160, ':Rp '+ String(this.formatPrice(sisa)))   


  //table data
  var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("basic-table"));     
  doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {
    margin: {
      top: 180,
      
  },

     styles: {
       
        fontsize: 10,
        cellPadding: 1.5,
        // overflow: 'linebreak',
        valign: 'middle',
        halign: 'center',
        lineColor: [0, 0, 0],
        lineWidth: 0.2
    },

  didDrawCell: function(rows) {
  var pageNumber = doc.internal.getCurrentPageInfo().pageNumber;
          
        
            if(pageNumber == 1){
                if (rows.row.index > 0 && rows.row.index % 11 === 0 && rows.column.index === rows.table.columns.length - 1) {
                    doc.addPage();
                }    
            }else{
              if (rows.row.index > 0 && rows.row.index % 30 === 0 && rows.column.index === rows.table.columns.length - 1) {

                   doc.addPage();
                }
        
          }
      }
  });

  addFooters(doc)
  doc.save("table.pdf");
}
```

}

can someone help ????